# can we use and operator to combine multiple jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `jQuery` to see if three text boxes are changed so I can send data through `AJAX`.

I tried a simple script:

```
$("#name, #position, #salary").change(function()
{
     console.log("All data are changed");
});
```

Where name, position and salary are the respective IDs of three text box.

The result was that when I change the first one:

[image]

And when I changed the second:

[image]

And here is the third one:

[image]

So, I've got the message when separately each text box is changed. What I do need is when the three are changed, display the message. I am new to jQuery, so I want to know if I can use something like `IF ... AND ... AND` in jQuery.

Comment: How does a human update 3 textboxes in a same time?

Comment: LOL, okay, see it like this, when `a human` type in the first box, then in the second then in the third, and without clicking on a button, those data will be sent to server. Good enough ?

Comment: So basically you want to check if those three are not empty when one of those change? We don't need to see complex things where there is not.

Comment: Yeah I know, the idea is to send data on change, with no submit button. I know I am making hard on myself and on you, but I thought it worth to test it

Comment: Exactly, but I am just trying some jQuery events, and how to combine multiple of them in the same function.

Comment: **STOP USING** `$(this).attr('id')`! Just use native javascript: `this.id`. Not everything has to be jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of validation frameworks have the concept of a dirty input once a user has changed the value. You could implement this and check when all your fields are dirty.

```js
$("#name, #position, #salary").change(function() {
  this.classList.add("dirty");
  if ($(".dirty").length === 3) {
    console.log("All data are changed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="position" />
<input id="salary" />
```

We can abstract this out into a jQuery plugin for re-usability

```js
$.fn.allChange = function(callback) {
  var $elements = this;
  $elements.change(function() {
    this.classList.add("dirty");
    if (callback && $elements.filter(".dirty").length === $elements.length) {
      callback.call($elements);
    }
  });
  return $elements;
}

$("#name, #position, #salary").allChange(function() {
  console.log("All data are changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="position" />
<input id="salary" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store changed inputs in an array, and check it's length to detect if all of them where changed.

```
var changedInputs = [];
$("#name, #position, #salary").change(function()
{
     changedInputs.push(this.id);
     if(changedInputs.length === 3) {
       alert('All 3 inputs where changed!');
     }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that if the person changes the same id 2 times, then would it work??

Comment: It was not mentioned in the op, but you can add some logic that performs `push`/`splice` based on input's value. Don't see any problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
var changedInputs = [];
$("#name, #position, #salary").change(function()
{
   if !(changedInputs.include(this.id) ){
     changedInputs.push(this.id);
     if(changedInputs.length == 3) {
        alert('All 3 inputs where changed!');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this approach. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ssnL8pu0/)

```
var isNameChanged, isPositionChanged, isSalaryChanged = false;

function fieldsChanged()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == 'name') isNameChanged = true;
    else if (id == 'position') isPositionChanged = true;
    else if (id == 'salary') isSalaryChanged = true;

  if (isNameChanged && isPositionChanged && isSalaryChanged) {
    console.log('All have been changed');
    isNameChanged = isPositionChanged = isSalaryChanged = false;
  }
}

$(function(){
    $('#name, #position, #salary').change(fieldsChanged);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the multiple selectors in a variable. On `.change()` loop through the elements in the multiple selector to test the input values. If all inputs have content an additional function can be called.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var $selectors = $('#input1, #input2, #input3');

  $selectors.change(function(){
    var allChanged = true;
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' was changed.');

    $selectors.each(function(){ 
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        allChanged = false;
      }
    });

    if (allChanged) {
      // $().ajax();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<input id="input3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a class:

```
<input class="need">
<input class="need">
<input class="need">
$(".need").change(function()
{
  var all = 0;
    $(".need").each(function(i,v){
        if ($(v).val().length >0 ) {
          all+=1; 
        }
    });
    if(all.length == 3) {
       alert('All 3 inputs where changed!');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution:

```
var needed = ["name", "position", "salary"];

$("#name, #position, #salary").change(function()
{
    if(needed.length == 0) return;
    needed.splice(needed.indexOf($(this).attr('id')), 1);
    if(needed.length == 0)
        console.log("All data are changed");
});
```

first, you need to init the array "needed" to all required fields
then, when a field is changed, you remove that field from the needed array
once the array is empty, all required values are changed ;)

the first condition is to ensure not to log the message more than once

Answer (score 0):

You can compare current input value to default one, then the logic could be like following:

*btw, i set a common class for all inputs to check, because this is how it should be done imho...*

```js
$('.inputToCheck').on('change', function() {
  var allInputsChanged = !$('.inputToCheck').filter(function() {
    return this.value === this.defaultValue;
  }).length;
  if (allInputsChanged) alert('All inputs changed!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" class="inputToCheck">
<input id="position" class="inputToCheck">
<input id="salary" class="inputToCheck">
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps